# delay in php file inclusion or execution

Tags: php

in my php page several files are included and i want all to be loaded on page load except one which i want to load after 3 seconds of complete page load.
i tried php sleep but its delaying entire page for that much second.

i thought of using lazy load but then i think it will load that file in background but will not show for  3 seconds.
if it will load immediately then my purpose will not solve.as the data will be inserted in mysql database.i want data after three seconds to be inserted in mysql

i tried this but not working

```
$rnd='0';
if($rnd=='0')
{
  sleep(3);
         include('/xxxxxxxxx/include.php');
    }
```

any method is acceptable just it should serve my purpose

Comment: Set timeout in JavaScript on page load and call ajax which will update your database table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "delay" some part of your website using php. PHP is run on the server side and generate an html page which is sent to your browser.

A good way to acheive what you want is using javascript and css to hide/show part of the html generated by the php on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

When the site is loaded, the PHP process has ended. You cannot load it asynchronously while the PHP process is running.

Depending on what you want and what the concrete goal is, you could maybe use JavaScript with XmlHttpRequest.